# Не обновляются данные в индексе в Azure Search

Tags: c#, .net, search, azure, azure-storage

Использую Azure Search в .Net приложении, создал индекс, и для него индексатор, первый раз индексатор обработал все данные которые были, но потом после изменения значения в некоторых записях, при повторной индексации не обрабатывает ни одной записи, попросту не видит изменений, при добавлении и удалении записей та же проблема, подскажите, может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ответ на свой вопрос. Перед тем как создавать индекс нужно было включить отслеживания изменений для базы данных и для конкретной таблицы. После включения (выполняется с помощью SQL-запросов:

ALTER DATABASE DataBaseName
SET CHANGE_TRACKING = ON
(CHANGE_RETENTION = 2 DAYS, AUTO_CLEANUP = ON) - для базы данных, и :
ALTER TABLE TableName 
ENABLE CHANGE_TRACKING 
WITH (TRACK_COLUMNS_UPDATED = ON) - для конкретной таблицы), нужно создать новый индекс (для него новый индексатор). 
С новым индексом обновление данных работает хорошо.